# create your own settings in xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration-files

I'm in a ASP.NET project where I need to give several parameters to the administrator that is going to install the website, like:

```
AllowUserToChangePanelLayout
AllowUserToDeleteCompany
```

etc...

My question is, will be a good thing to add this into the web.config file, using my own configSession or add as a profile varibles? or should I create a XML file for this?

What do you do and what are the cons and favs?

I originally thought about web.config but I then realized that I should mess up with Website configurations and my own web app configuration and that I should create a different file, them I read [this post](http://www.aspcode.net/Your-own-configuration-setting-section-in-webconfig.aspx) and now I'm on this place... should I do this or that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually use Settings - available via the project properties - Settings. These can be edited and saved in code, and I write a form / web page to edit them.

If you want to use the XML configuration, there's an attribute called file that reads external files.
You could have a web.config file and a someothername.config file. The someothername.config would have settings like:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConnString" value="my conn string" />
    <add key="MaxUsers" value="50" />
</appSettings>
```

And the web.config would have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="ExternalWeb.config">
        <add key="MyKey" value="MyValue" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

See [DevX](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18880) for the example I stole.

Comment: excellent idea :) I just added, tests it and works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: Be advised that the external file is cached. If you make changes to it, you'll have to restart the application to reload settings.

Comment: @JohnSaunders are you sure? I thought this works on all sections.

Comment: Only appSettings has the `file` attribute. Some other sections have the `configSource` attribute. It's not a requirement. Also, the `file` attribute has different semantics. If the file doesn't exist, it's not an error - the settings just dont' take effect. The `appSettings` stuff was for `user.config`.

Answer (score 2):

just to let you guys know that I did what [configurator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9536/configurator) recommended but with a twist.

instead of asking all the time (that I need) for

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
```

I just created a static class that would pull this values with what we call by Strongly typed values (so you don't need to remember all the values)

the **mySettings** class

```
public static class mySettings
{
    public enum SettingsType
    { UserPermitions, WebService, Alerts }
    public enum SectionType
    { AllowChangeLayout, AllowUserDelete, MaximumReturnsFromSearch, MaximumOnBatch, SendTo }

    public static String GetSettings(SettingsType type, SectionType section)
    {
        return
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[
                String.Format("{0}_{1}",
                    Enum.Parse(typeof(SettingsType), type.ToString()).ToString(),
                    Enum.Parse(typeof(SectionType), section.ToString()).ToString())
            ];
    }
}
```

the **web.config** appSettings part

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="myApp.config">
    <add key="UserPermitions_AllowChangeLayout" value="" />
    <add key="UserPermitions_AllowUserDelete" value="" />    

    <add key="WebService_MaximumReturnsFromSearch" value="" /> 

    <add key="Alerts_SendTo" value="" />
    <add key="Alerts_MaximumOnBatch" value="" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

the entire **myApp.config** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
###
### This file serves the propose of a quick configuration.
### Administrator can either change this values directly or use the 
###   Settings tab in the application.
###
-->
<appSettings>

  <!-- *** User Access Configuration *** -->
  <!-- Allow user to change the panels layout {1: Yes} {0: No} -->
  <add key="UserPermitions_AllowChangeLayout" value="1" />
  <!-- Allow user to delete a company fro monitoring -->
  <add key="UserPermitions_AllowUserDelete" value="1" />

  <!-- *** Web Service configuration *** -->
  <!-- Maximum responses from the search service -->
  <add key="WebService_MaximumReturnsFromSearch" value="10" />

  <!-- *** Allerts configuration *** -->
  <!-- Send the alerts to the email writeen below -->
  <add key="Alerts_SendTo" value="bruno.in.dk@gmail.com" />
  <!-- Send an alert when user import more than the number bellow -->
  <add key="Alerts_MaximumOnBatch" value="10" />

</appSettings>
```

So, now I call like this:

```
p.value = mySettings.GetSettings(
             mySettings.SettingsType.WebService, 
             mySettings.SectionType.MaximumReturnsFromSearch);
```

Hope that helps someone with the same problem :)

Comment: This doesn't look very scalable because you'll have to keep the enums updated all the time... if you want named properties, a .settings resource file is probably more practical. It's not maintainable from outside the app, but you could use it as a strongly typed map for the .config key strings.

Comment: By the way (offtopic), isn't it supposed to be "permissions" instead of "permitions"?

Comment: Whoa, what's the point of `Enum.Parse(typeof(SettingsType) , type.ToString()).ToString()`? Isn't it the same as `type.ToString()`?

Answer (score 1):

You may also put your configurations in a settings file. In your project, open Properties and go to Settings which looks
[like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX8XB.gif)

To access the values in your code, use `Properties.Settings.YourSettingName;`

Use `Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();` to refresh your settings during runtime

Comment: My class library settings were always using the default values, even if I changed them in the config file. Calling Reload() before getting the settings worked for me, even if I didn't change the setting during runtime. Do you know why calling Reload() was necessary?