# ConfigurationManager reading wrong file - Web.config instead of App.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configurationmanager

I was working on ASP.NET MVC project and decided to extract some functionality to a separate class library project (in the same solution).

I moved some of the elements in `<appSettings></appSettings>` from `Web.config` in main project (let's call it project A) to `App.config` in class library project (let's call it project B). I added a reference to System.Configuration.dll to access the ConfigurationManager in project B.

Sample App.config file is for project B is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Key1" value="Value1"/>
    <add key="Key2" value="Value2"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I access these settings as follows (in project B).

```
string key1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"];
string key2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key2"];
```

I noticed that the values for `key1` and `key2` returned by `ConfigurationManager` are `null`.

When debugging I see that `ConfigurationManager` pull values from the original `Web.config` in project A (the other entires in `<appsettings></appsettings>` section that I did not move to project B)!

This does not make any sense to me. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong, so I could access settings in App.config?

Thanks.

Comment: Web projects use web.config, not app.config.  Why do you want to change the name of the configuration file?

Comment: It's a separate project that is using App.config. The main web project references this project and uses its functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`App.config` that resides in a Class Library project would not be loaded (at least not without extra effort), the only configuration loaded by the framework is the **Client** configuration (i.e the `Web.config` of a project that references and uses your Class Library).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355821/how-can-i-make-a-net-class-library-read-its-own-configuration-file) for possible solutions.

Comment: I guess in my case it is better to keep all settings in Web.config then, since it is the Client that's providing the values. Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: Did you look into the possible solutions in the link? it's relatively easy to achieve

Comment: You're right, it's relatively easy to do. I'll consider doing it that way.