# Reading configuration file from .NET Source Project, not from target

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In .NET solutions, we can read settings from configuration files, such as `web.config` or `app.config`. But I found a problem while using these resources. In a solution, I created a Class Library Project and an ASP.NET Project, both of them have a "something.config" file. In Class Library, it is called `App.Config`, and in ASP.NET, obviously, `Web.config`.

I created a method in a class in the Class Library Project and invoked it in ASP.NET. These methods gets some settings from `app.config`, but if I try to use in my Web project, the method read from `web.config`, in ASP.NET project, what is not desirable.

How can I do to make the method in Class Library Project read the `App.Config` from corresponding project, not from web project?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690313/using-app-config-with-a-class-library

Comment: In general a library has no business accessing config files. The application should pass the configuration to the libraries it uses.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so then show some code the way you are trying to do it..

Comment: But in cases when a class library application cannot always depends on target application, it can generate a problem in souce application. My idea is to prevent my classes to make errors because client publishing failures (i.e. forgetting keys or wrong values).

Comment: @Joker There has no secrets, it is just using the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingname"]. But if we use it in class library project, it will read from web.config on web project, not from app.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the application you are running.

The web application is the entry point hence it'll use the web.config.

You can put the values/sections contained in the app.config into the web.config and it'll be read.

After digging out the configuration manager class i've added the below to read config file associated with an assembly.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var tempValue = config.AppSettings["setting_name"];
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I wanted to avoid to do it. I didn't want to depend on the person who will publish the web project to put in the web.config file in web application, while I have the same settings in class library project. I wanted to make the method always read the app.config in the source project, where it has been written.

Comment: @MatheusGelinski i've modified my answer to include an option

Comment: It can be a stupid question, but what is this "Assembly_name" (or type)?

Comment: @MatheusGelinski refresh the page ... i've modified the answer because i realize you'll be accessing the config values from the dll in question so the best option would be to use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().

Comment: I can't execute the last line, but I changed to:
var settings = config.GetSection("appSettings") as AppSettingsSection;
var tempValue = settings.Settings["test"].Value; But you answer helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`App.config` that places in the class library project wouldn't load by default. The only config file will be loaded is the client configuration (`web.config`).

To configure the project to load the local class library config file which is `app.config`.

You need the following code to do that:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { 
        ExeConfigFilename = path + "app.config" 
    }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

For more details, visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355821/how-can-i-make-a-net-class-library-read-its-own-configuration-file/5355918#5355918).