# wcf service endpoint null

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have this App.config in my wcf service library:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="addr" value="net.tcp://localhost:22222/AdministrationService/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Watchman.WcfService.AdministrationService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:22222/AdministrationService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="Ep1" address="net.tcp://localhost/AdministrationService/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DuplexBinding" contract="Watchman.WcfService.Interfaces.IAdministration"/>
        <endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="10000"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost/AdministrationService/Ep1/wsdl"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DuplexBinding" sendTimeout="00:00:01">
          <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

but I got error:

```
"The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified."
```

It seems like application doesn't this tcp.net endpoint. Why?

Comment: Have you specified endpoint address in  your client?

Comment: @Reniuz I generate app.config in client with svcutil...but I just noticed that I get "<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding_IAdministration" contract="IAdministration" name="DefaultBinding_IAdministration_IAdministration" />" instead of my net.tcp endpoint. Why?

Comment: Iam not 100% sure but maybe you need to add `<behavior name="metadataSupport">` in serviceBehaviors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that svcutil generates bad endpoint in wcf client project. There's

```
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding_IAdministration" 
          contract="IAdministration" 
          name="DefaultBinding_IAdministration_IAdministration" />"
```

instead of my `net.tcp` endpoint.

I also observed that's because of generation of `ProxyFile.cs` and `App.config` from

```
svcutil WcfServiceLibrary.dll
```

If I generate this files from metadata like:

```
svcutil net.tcp://localhost:8080/AdministrationService/mex /language:C# /out:ProxyFile.cs /config:App.config
```

then it works fine (in App config is described correct net.tcp endpoint)

**Does anyone knows why cooperation svcutil with *.dll goes wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

> I have this App.config in my wcf service library

You cannot have an app.config in a wcf class library and expect WCF to read settings from it. It doesn't make sense. Config files such as app.config are defined in the final executable application project (such as a Console application, WinForms, WPF, ...). Or if it is a web application you use a web.config. But there is not such thing as app.config for a class library. So you might need to include this WCF configuration in the app/web.config of the application using your class library.

Comment: -1: I believe you [*can* have an app.config on a class library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690313/using-app-config-with-a-class-library).

Comment: @Peter K., and how are you gonna tell WCF to use settings that are defined in this *custom app.config* file instead of where WCF expects settings to be => which is the real app.config, the one defined for the application?

Comment: I put it into wcf service library and to console application that host this service - nothing has changed

Comment: @Saint, well maybe showing your code might help as well. You have posted only some `app.config` which is not clear where did you deploy, ... We don't even know (yet) how are you trying to expose/consume this service.

Comment: @Darin: I agree that the settings need to be in the eventual config file of the app using them. Your statement `You cannot have an app.config in a class library` is wrong, or at best misleading.

Comment: @Peter K., OK, I said this in the context of the question: which is WCF. But I agree with you that it could be misinterpreted. I will fix my answer.

Comment: I just noticed that svcutil generate bad endpoint in wcf client. There's "<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding_IAdministration"
                contract="IAdministration" name="DefaultBinding_IAdministration_IAdministration" />" instead of my net.tcp endpoint. Hmm...why?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a base address for net.tcp, so the address on the net.tcp endpoint becomes a relative address. So, effectively the address of the end point becomes net.tcp://localhost:22222/AdministrationService/localhost/AdministrationService/.

Change the address on the endpoint to a relative address and re-generate the proxy class using svcutil.

Comment: Kiran Mothe, I did it but nothing change. Show my comment to Darin Dimitrov and @Peter K. below.