# ConfigurationManager does not point to correct app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I am trying to use `ConfigurationManager` to get the connection string from a project call *FileShareAccessLibrary*.

This is the code I am writting in order to do this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FileShareAccessLibrary"].ConnectionString
```

This is the content of app.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FileShareAccessLibrary" connectionString="......"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="FileShareAccessLibrary.Properties.Settings"
      connectionString="..."
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I run my app I get a `NullReferenceException` because `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FileShareAccessLibrary"]` returns null.

While debugging I noticed that none of the two connection strings are stored inside `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` so I figured that the `ConfigurationManager` is pointing to another file.

In my project I have not other `app.config` file.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?
Why is `ConfigurationManager` not getting my connection string?

Comment: WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FileShareAccessLibrary"].ToString()

Comment: What type of project is this? Is there any .config file in the output directory when you build the project?

Comment: add a <clear/> tag inside your <connectionStrings> tag before other tags, and test again.

Comment: Is your actual app.config file named "yourapplication.exe.config"? app.config is copied by Visual Studio when it compiles to match the executable name, plus ".config".

Comment: The project is a C# class library

Comment: the app.config file is called app.config the project name is FileShareAccessLibrary , the solution is N.Common

Comment: This doesn't work because you are trying to access your application's app.config from a class library. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690313/using-app-config-with-a-class-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your FileShareAccessLibrary project is a class library rather than a windows forms application or console application then you will need to move the connection strings (and app settings if you have any) from the FileShareAccessLibrary config file to the config file of the application(s) that reference the FileShareAccessLibrary dll.

Comment: What if I want to make some integration tests (in a separate Class library project)? Where should I put my connection string for those integration tests?