# How do I manage the configuration settings for a class library?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET class library that needs configuration parameters, their values are different for every deployment. I would normally store these in an app.config.

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690313/using-app-config-with-a-class-library), **however the entry point is not a .NET application**: it's a C# class library that gets called by a C++/CLI wrapper that exports C functions, which get called by a native application.

Shoud I just read a configuration file manually or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I would provide my own xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it doesn't matter whether the running application is a .NET application or not: the runtime tries to load `ProcessName.exe.config` anyway and I can put (or link to) my configuration there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a settings file. Read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx#settingscs_topic3

Comment: Those settings don't load automatically in my case. How do I load them?